# submitting checkboxes with Thymeleaf + SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have a SpringBoot app. with this thymelaf template, that works fine when submitting:

```
 <div class="form-group required-control">
                                    <label for="gre">GRE</label>
                                    <input id="gre" type="checkbox" name="gre" th:checked="*{gre}" th:onclick="submit()"   />

                                </div>
```

but when I add another checkbox, It always take in account the first one, regardless which one I click

```
 <div class="form-group required-control">
                                    <label for="gre">GRE</label>
                                    <input id="gre" type="checkbox" name="gre" th:checked="*{gre}" th:onclick="submit()"   />

 <label for="gre2">GRE2</label>
                                    <input id="gre2" type="checkbox" name="gre2" th:checked="*{gre2}" th:onclick="submit()"   />


                                </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no technical problem here. I think there is a problem with your `submit()` function, because I created a normal form and tried your same instance, and all selection combinations worked correctly.

*I am adding the entity, controller and html files respectively for example.*

```
public class Example {

    private boolean gre;
    private boolean gre2;

    public Example() {
    }

    // getter/setter ...
}
```

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/example")
public class ExampleController {

    @GetMapping("/create")
    public String createExample(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("example", new Example());
        return "example-form";
    }

    @PostMapping("/insert")
    public String insertExample(Model model, Example example) {
        model.addAttribute("example", example);
        return "example-form";
    }
}
```

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<body>
<div>
    <form action="/example/insert" method="post" th:object="${example}">
        <div class="form-group required-control">
            <label for="gre">GRE</label>
            <input id="gre" type="checkbox" name="gre" th:checked="*{gre}" />
            <label for="gre2">GRE 2</label>
            <input id="gre2" type="checkbox" name="gre2" th:checked="*{gre2}" />
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Submit Form</button>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to add an attribute into the Model, you can receive checkbox condition via HttpServletRequest.

```
@GetMapping("/create")
public String createExample() {
    return "example-form";
}

@PostMapping("/insert")
public String insertExample(User user, HttpServletRequest request) {
    user.setGre(request.getParameter("gre") != null);
    user.setGre2(request.getParameter("gre2") != null);
    userServiceImp.updateUser(editedUser); //for example updating user in database
    return "/";
}
```

HTML will be like this:

```
    <form th:action="/insert" method="post">
        <div class="form-group required-control">
            <label>GRE</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="gre"/>
            <label>GRE 2</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="gre2"/>
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Submit Form</button>
    </form>
```