# Passing a list of object to the controller [Spring Boot + Thymeleaf]

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm new to Spring Boot and Thymeleaf and I’m having a hard time with them.
I am having a lot of difficulty with POSTing back a form to the controller, where the form should contain a list of objects that the user may select and edit.
I want to allow the user to select the types of "Tampone" he could offer and, for each one of them, the corresponding price.
So I want to return back to the controller a list of only the selected items, with their price.

These are my DTOs:

```
package com.uniba.di.dfmdevelop.labservice.dto;

import lombok.Data;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
import lombok.ToString;

import javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode
@ToString
public class LaboratorioDTO extends UtenteGenericoDTO {

    @NotEmpty
    @Size(min = 2, message = "Il campo deve contenere almeno 2 caratteri")
    private String nomeLaboratorio;

    @NotEmpty
    @Size(min = 10, max = 10, message = "Il campo deve contenere esattamente 10 caratteri")
    private String numeroTelefono;

    @NotEmpty
    @Size(min = 2, message = "Il campo deve contenere almeno 2 caratteri")
    private String indirizzoStradale;

    @NotEmpty
    @Size(min = 27, max = 27, message = "Il campo deve contenere esattamente 27 caratteri")
    private String codiceIban;

    @NotEmpty
    @Size(min = 11, max = 11, message = "Il campo deve contenere esattamente 11 caratteri")
    private String partitaIva;

    // Memorizza i tamponi inseriti in fase di registrazione
    private List<TamponeDTO> lista_tamponi = new ArrayList<>();

    public LaboratorioDTO(String indirizzoEmail,
                          String password,
                          String confermaPassword,
                          String ruolo,
                          String nomeLaboratorio,
                          String numeroTelefono,
                          String indirizzoStradale,
                          String codiceIban,
                          String partitaIva) {
        super(indirizzoEmail,password,ruolo,confermaPassword);
        this.nomeLaboratorio = nomeLaboratorio;
        this.numeroTelefono = numeroTelefono;
        this.indirizzoStradale = indirizzoStradale;
        this.codiceIban = codiceIban;
        this.partitaIva = partitaIva;
    }

    public LaboratorioDTO() {
        super();
    }

    public void addTamponeDTO(TamponeDTO tamponeDTO) {
        this.lista_tamponi.add(tamponeDTO);
    }
}
```

```
package com.uniba.di.dfmdevelop.labservice.dto;

import lombok.*;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
@ToString
public class TamponeDTO {

    private boolean selected;
    private Long tampone_id;
    private String nome;
    private double prezzo;

    public TamponeDTO(Long id, String nome) {
        this.selected = false;
        this.tampone_id = id;
        this.nome = nome;
    }
}
```

This is the registration form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <title>RegistrazioneLaboratorio</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u"
          crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-F3w7mX95PdgyTmZZMECAngseQB83DfGTowi0iMjiWaeVhAn4FJkqJByhZMI3AhiU" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link th:href="@{~/css/registrazioneStyle.css}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fontss.googleapis.com/css2?family=Muli:wght@300;400;700;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="js/laboratorio.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

    <div class="header">
        <div class="logo" style="padding-left: 20px;">
            <a th:href="@{/index}"><img th:src="@{~/img/logo.png}" height="53px" width="200px"></a>
        </div>
    </div>

<br>
<br>
<!-- Create HTML registration form -->
<div class="container" style="margin-top: 20px;">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <br><br>

            <div th:if="${param.fail_send}">
                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                    Impossibile inviare il link di conferma all'indirizzo e-mail specificato.
                </div>
            </div>

            <form th:action="@{/laboratorio/registration}" th:object="${laboratorioDTO}" th:method="post">

                <!--/*@thymesVar id="indirizzoEmail" type="com.uniba.di.dfmdevelop.labservice.dto.LaboratorioDTO"*/-->
                <input class="form-control" type="hidden"
                       th:attr="value = ${laboratorioDTO.indirizzoEmail}" th:field="*{indirizzoEmail}"/>

                <!--/*@thymesVar id="password" type="com.uniba.di.dfmdevelop.labservice.dto.LaboratorioDTO"*/-->
                <input class="form-control" type="hidden"
                       th:attr="value = ${laboratorioDTO.password}" th:field="*{password}"/>

                <!--/*@thymesVar id="conferma_password" type="com.uniba.di.dfmdevelop.labservice.dto.LaboratorioDTO"*/-->
                <input class="form-control" type="hidden"
                       th:attr="value = ${laboratorioDTO.conferma_password}" th:field="*{conferma_password}"/>

                <!--/*@thymesVar id="ruolo" type="com.uniba.di.dfmdevelop.labservice.dto.LaboratorioDTO"*/-->
                <input class="form-control" type="hidden"
                       th:attr="value = ${laboratorioDTO.ruolo}" th:field="*{ruolo}"/>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <!--/*@thymesVar id="nomeLaboratorio" type="com.uniba.di.dfmdevelop.labservice.dto.LaboratorioDTO"*/-->
                    <label class="control-label" for="nomeLaboratorio"> Nome Laboratorio </label> <input
                        id="nomeLaboratorio" class="form-control" th:field="*{nomeLaboratorio}"
                        th:errorClass="is-invalid" required autofocus="autofocus" />
                    <div th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('nomeLaboratorio')}" th:errors="*{nomeLaboratorio}" class="invalid-feedback"></div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <!--/*@thymesVar id="numeroTelefono" type="com.uniba.di.dfmdevelop.labservice.dto.LaboratorioDTO"*/-->
                    <label class="control-label" for="numeroTelefono"> Numero di telefono </label> <input
                        id="numeroTelefono" class="form-control" th:field="*{numeroTelefono}"
                        th:errorClass="is-invalid" required autofocus="autofocus" />
                    <div th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('numeroTelefono')}" th:errors="*{numeroTelefono}" class="invalid-feedback"></div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <!--/*@thymesVar id="indirizzoStradale" type="com.uniba.di.dfmdevelop.labservice.dto.LaboratorioDTO"*/-->
                    <label class="control-label" for="indirizzoStradale"> Indirizzo Sede </label> <input
                        id="indirizzoStradale" class="form-control" th:field="*{indirizzoStradale}"
                        th:errorClass="is-invalid" required autofocus="autofocus" />
                    <div th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('indirizzoStradale')}" th:errors="*{indirizzoStradale}" class="invalid-feedback"></div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <!--/*@thymesVar id="codiceIban" type="com.uniba.di.dfmdevelop.labservice.dto.LaboratorioDTO"*/-->
                    <label class="control-label" for="codiceIban"> Codice IBAN </label> <input
                        id="codiceIban" class="form-control" th:field="*{codiceIban}"
                        th:errorClass="is-invalid" required autofocus="autofocus" />
                    <div th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('codiceIban')}" th:errors="*{codiceIban}" class="invalid-feedback"></div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <!--/*@thymesVar id="partitaIva" type="com.uniba.di.dfmdevelop.labservice.dto.LaboratorioDTO"*/-->
                    <label class="control-label" for="partitaIva"> Partita IVA </label> <input
                        id="partitaIva" class="form-control" th:field="*{partitaIva}"
                        th:errorClass="is-invalid" required autofocus="autofocus" />
                    <div th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('partitaIva')}" th:errors="*{partitaIva}" class="invalid-feedback"></div>
                </div>

                <br>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label"> Seleziona i tipi di tamponi offerti e il relativo costo: </label>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <div class="input-group-text">
                            <input style="padding-left: 3px" type="checkbox" name="molecolare" id="molecolare" onclick="abilitaDisabilita(this)">
                        </div>
                        <span class="input-group-text" style="size: 20px">Tampone Molecolare</span>
                        <span class="input-group-text">&euro;</span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="prezzoMolecolare" placeholder="Es. 20,00" disabled>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <div class="input-group-text">
                            <input style="padding-left: 3px" type="checkbox" name="antigenico" id="antigenico" onclick="abilitaDisabilita(this)">
                        </div>
                        <span class="input-group-text" style="padding-right: 12px">Tampone Antigenico</span>
                        <span class="input-group-text">&euro;</span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="prezzoAntigenico" placeholder="Es. 20,00" disabled>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <div class="input-group-text">
                            <input style="padding-left: 3px" type="checkbox" name="sierologico" id="sierologico" onclick="abilitaDisabilita(this)">
                        </div>
                        <span class="input-group-text">Tampone Sierologico</span>
                        <span class="input-group-text">&euro;</span>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="prezzoSierologico" placeholder="Es. 20,00" disabled>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="submit" class="button">Registati</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't know how to do the Thymeleaf integration for the last 3 checkboxes.
The other fields are POSTing fine.

The GET method for the registration form, calls the form in this way:

```
LaboratorioDTO laboratorioDTO = new LaboratorioDTO();
              
laboratorioDTO.setIndirizzoEmail(request.getIndirizzoEmail());
laboratorioDTO.setPassword(request.getPassword());
laboratorioDTO.setConferma_password(request.getConferma_password());
laboratorioDTO.setRuolo(request.getRuolo());

laboratorioDTO.addTamponeDTO(new TamponeDTO(Long.valueOf(0),"Molecolare"));
laboratorioDTO.addTamponeDTO(new TamponeDTO(Long.valueOf(1),"Antigenico"));
laboratorioDTO.addTamponeDTO(new TamponeDTO(Long.valueOf(2),"Sierologico"));

model.addAttribute("laboratorioDTO", laboratorioDTO);
return "laboratorio/registration";
```

This is the POST method in the controller, where the object should be submitted:

```
    @PostMapping("laboratorio/registration")
    public String register(@Valid @ModelAttribute("laboratorioDTO") LaboratorioDTO request,
                           BindingResult bindingResult,
                           Model model) {
        log.info("Starting registratiom Labooratorio");
        model.addAttribute("laboratorioDTO", request);
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()){
            log.error("Error in Laboratorio registration");
            return "laboratorio/registration";}

        try {
            log.info("Trying to register...");
            registrationService.register(request, "laboratorioDTO");
        } catch (CustomException e) {
            switch (e.getMessage()) {
                case ErrorMessage.EMAIL_ALREADY_TAKEN:
                    log.error("... Mail already taken");
                    return "redirect:/registration?already_taken";
                case ErrorMessage.EMAIL_FAIL_SEND:
                    log.error("... Error in sending request");
                    return "redirect:/registration?fail_send";
            }
        }
        // Successo
        return "redirect:/login?success";
    }
```

Maybe I have to rewrite all the code.
Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65464897/1063509 could you please check this one

Comment: Ok thanks, I solve my problem putting 3 boolean attribute and 3 double attribute in the LaboratorioDTO. But the question for getting a list of TamponeDTO is still open.